# ecto table not being created

Tags: database, elixir, ecto

I run `mix ecto.migrate` and have this file in my migrations:

**api/priv/repo/migrations/20180724182549_create_user_table.exs:**

```
defmodule Api.Repo.Migrations.CreateUserTable do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :first_name, :string
      add :last_name, :string
      add :email, :string
      add :u_id, :string
  end

  create unique_index(:users, [:u_id])
end
```

It does not create the user table. What could the reason be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing `end` for `do`:

```
defmodule Api.Repo.Migrations.CreateUserTable do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :first_name, :string
      add :last_name, :string
      add :email, :string
      add :u_id, :string
    end # this was missing
  end

  create unique_index(:users, [:u_id])
end
```